# GetExports<type> do not return items with a contractName

Tags: c#-4.0, mef

I have problem with MEF exports.

I have family of the object which implements one interface. They all are published with a custom publish attribute. Attribute requires a string which is passed as a *ContractName*. Additionally attribute sets up the *ContractType* to be one shared interface.

My attribute class looks like that:

```
public class ItemCreatorAttribute : ExportAttribute, IItemCreatorMetadata
{
    public ItemCreatorAttribute(String type)
        : base(type, typeof(IItemCreator)){..}
```

Everything is working nice if I want to import just one of the object and I am using both contract name and type. However my attempts to get a list of object just by type(`IItemCreator` in this case) failed.

I have tried to get items using a `Container.GetExports` and `ImportMany` attribute, both method returns no results.

Any ideas?

Regards
Szymon

**Edit**

I have solve the problem by iterating through the Catalog's parts, but I am still searching for nicer solution.

```
var exportsCollection = new List<ExportDefinition>();
foreach (var export in Container.Catalog.Parts)
{
    foreach (var exportDef in export.ExportDefinitions)
    {
        if (exportDef.Metadata.ContainsKey("ExportTypeIdentity"))
            if (contractType.Equals(exportDef.Metadata["ExportTypeIdentity"]))
                exportsCollection.Add(exportDef);
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**

aL3891 I have thought the same but I made a test when I am trying to get a list just with Contract Type and then with both Contract type and name. My expectation was  that contract type only will return all available items. However it seems to set it to null and searching for items of type provided with a empty contract name.

```
// No results
var test = Container.GetExports<IItemCreator>();
// 1 Result
var test2 = Container.GetExports<IItemCreator>("Foo");
```

Comment: hm i might have misunderstood your problem, can you post the code where you use ImportMany / Getexports()?

Answer (score 1):

Does the things you're exporting have any imports of their own? if that is the case and mef is unable to satisfy those imports, they wont show up in composition.

Alot of times when i've had ImportMany attributed properties ending up empty, its because whatever was supposed to go in that property had imports of their own that wasnt found.

Mef calls this [Stable composition](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/11/01/stable-composition-in-mef.aspx)